# Web Server makes 404 error while accessing spring form from RestTemplet

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, form-authentication

I am developing a RestTemplet where their is Authentication on Server.if some one try to access particular url than server open the default spring form to authenticate client. IT gives me a 404 error while passing a correct credential. IT is only happened when i try to access that URL from RestTemplet if I directly access the port of Server and try to access that particular URL than it works.